# Algorithm for finding the root element

Tags: data-structures, trees

I have the following interface:

```
public interface TreeElement<T>{
    public List<TreeElement<T>> getChildren();
}
```

Now, suppose I have a collection of `TreeElement<T>` representing a ***valid*** tree. How to find it's root element? Is there something more efficient than iterating over the whole collection?

Comment: Specific languages are off-topic here. Even more so anonymous programming languages. Could you explain the problem in more general terms than a specific program fragment. I have no idea how your syntax is to be read. If it is an algorithmic question, you should be able to specify abstractedly, and topossibly propose a solution in pseudo-code.

Comment: Iterating over the whole collection doing what?

Comment: @babou I think this question can be reasonably read as, "if I have a tree data structure in which nodes know their children (but not their parent), can I find the root in time $o(n)$"?

Comment: The question is underspecified. Are we only allowed to use this interface? If we control the implementation, we can just remember the root and get $O(1)$-time retrieval.

Comment: @Raphael No, I can't remember the root element. All I have si the collection of elements which "knows" about their childrend (if any). I need to find by that condition the root element, assuming that the elements are a valid tree.

Comment: @babou checking if the element is a child of something else.

Comment: @Raphael Then why not state the algorithmic problem for what it is, rather than
use this convoluted and rather unprecise way.  I would add that the
question asks about efficiency, not asymptotics. I can imagine ways of
getting the right answer without necessarily having to examine all the
elements. IMHO, this is a bad question, and I suspect a weak or wrong
answer. But both are so unprecise. And I still do not know what
operation is supposed to be iterated.

Comment: @babou What's wrong with the question? Tell me so that I'll be able to modify it. I have the list of tree elements and I need to find its root. What's wrong?

Comment: @babou It may be a problem dump, or an honest question by a practitioner without formal CS education. I can't tell. I agree that the question is less than clear; curiously, though, there are no votes to that effect.

Comment: @St.Antario See my earlier comment. The answer depends on what exactly you are allowed to do/modify.

Comment: The question is asked as a (Java?) programming issue. A proper more
language independent version would be something like: We have a
TreeNode structure that is used to build tree. Assuming we have a set
of such TreeNode's forming a single valid tree, that can be
enumerated, and using only a getChildren fuction/method on the nodes,
we want to determine which node is the root of the tree. Is there
something more efficient than iterating over the whole set of
TreeNode's? Prferably you should make precise what each iteration is
supposed to be doing, if that is precise for you. CC @Raphael

Comment: The correctness of the answer you accepted is dependent on subtle details of the problem asked. CC@Raphael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will make slightly stronger assumptions than that are provided in the question: we have a data structure, representing a tree, that consists of an array of vertices of the tree (allowing random access) and given a vertex, we have access to an array containing that vertex' children (again allowing random access). Furthermore we can check vertices for equality, and given a vertex we can (in $O(1)$ time) locate it in the main array.

On a tree of $n$ nodes, any strategy must take at least $\Omega(n)$ time in the worst case.

Consider a path of $n$ vertices. Define a vertex to be "examined" if it is accessed via the main array, via a children array or is reported as the root. Every non-leaf vertex must be examined by the algorithm: if some non-leaf vertex $v$ is not examined, we can make $v$ the root, making $v$'s child a child of $v$'s predecessor. This is not seen by the algorithm and it will incorrectly report the old root: making $v$ changes its children array (which is not seen by the algorithm as $v$ is not accessed at all) and changes the child array of $v$'s parent (which by the assumption of $v$ not being examined is not seen by the algorithm either).

Thus every non-leaf vertex in a path must be examined and any algorithm thus takes $\Omega(n)$ time.

Comment: I do not understand how examining solves a problem, unless you examine something specific in order to decide somethin. Neither the question nor the answer is very explicit about what is going on.

Comment: Unless you state precisely what you mean by "examining an element", I consider that you have no proof.

Comment: @babou I have clarified my proof and restated the question in my answer.

Comment: Nice rewriting (thanks), and good basis for discussion. I do not
dispute your worst case asymptotic time. What I dispute is that you
have to examine all vertices. Actually, when lucky, you could ignore
more than half of them in the case of a complete binary tree. The
point is that you have to know the total number of vertices, and for
each node its number of children (you can do that without examining
them). If at some point the number of unexamined children equals the
number of remaining nodes, whatever is the current root candidate has
to be the root: leafs are uninteresting.

Comment: @babou My claim that "every non-leaf vertex must be examined" only applies to the example of a path. In the best case you examine only $1$ vertex, namely when the tree consists of a single vertex with $n-1$ children.

Comment: Well, It was pretty late here when I got your new version, and I read it too fast (assuming it was only a rewriting, since you did not say otherwise). The "non-leaf" restriction on examined vertices was not in your first version of the answer. And that was what bothered me.